# Luasql and SQLite?

Tags: windows, sqlite, lua, luasql

I just got started looking at Lua as an easy way to access the SQLite DLL, but I ran into an error while trying to use the DB-agnostic LuaSQL module:

```
require "luasql.sqlite"
module "luasql.sqlite"

print("Content-type: Text/html\n")

print("Hello!")
```

Note that I'm trying to start from the most basic setup, so only have the following files in the work directory, and sqlite.dll is actually the renamed sqlite3.dll from the [LuaForge](http://luaforge.net/frs/?group_id=12) site:

```
Directory of C:\Temp
<DIR> luasql
lua5.1.exe
lua5.1.dll
hello.lua

Directory of C:\Temp\luasql
sqlite.dll
```

Am I missing some binaries that would explain the error?

Thank you.

---

Edit: I renamed the DLL to its original sqlite3.dll and updated the source to reflect this (originally renamed it because that's how it was called in a sample I found).

At this point, here's what the code looks like...

```
require "luasql.sqlite3"

-- attempt to call field 'sqlite' (a nil value)
env = luasql.sqlite()

env:close()
```

...  and the error message I'm getting:

```
C:\>lua5.1.exe hello.lua
lua5.1.exe: hello.lua:4: attempt to call field 'sqlite' (a nil value)
```

---

Edit: Found what it was: env = luasql.sqlite3() instead of env = luasql.sqlite().

For newbies like me, here's a complete example with the latest [SQLite LuaSQL driver](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/):

```
require "luasql.sqlite3"

env = luasql.sqlite3()
conn = env:connect("test.sqlite")

assert(conn:execute("create table if not exists tbl1(one varchar(10), two smallint)"))
assert(conn:execute("insert into tbl1 values('hello!',10)"))
assert(conn:execute("insert into tbl1 values('goodbye',20)"))

cursor = assert(conn:execute("select * from tbl1"))
row = {}
while cursor:fetch(row) do
    print(table.concat(row, '|'))
end

cursor:close()
conn:close()

env:close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is the DLL renamed?  What error are you getting?

Comment: The example given above will give the following error with Lua 5.1.4: `lua: sql.lua:3: attempt to index global 'luasql' (a nil value)`. This is because `require` no longer defines globals. Changing the first line to `luasql = require "luasql.sqlite3"` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't rename the DLL file: This will cause Lua not to find the initialization function in the DLL (which is named the same as the DLL).
2. You don't need the `module` call, just `require`. `module` is used when you are creating a module, not when you use it.

---

Edit: According to the LuaSQL documentation, it looks like you need to call `luasql.sqlite3()` instead of `luasql.sqlite()`.

Comment: Thanks guys for the input. I got further, but still getting an error, so updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I've recently used luasql, and it is `sqlite3`.  Works like a charm, then.

Answer (score 0):

In your edited snippet you are loading the `luasql.sqlite3` module and trying to access the `luasql.sqlite` driver. Note that `sqlite3` is not the same as `sqlite`...

Comment: Yup, figured it out a few minutes after posting the Edit ;-) Works great now. Thank you.